# How do I return objects' attributes in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-views

I am working on a friendship system with Django and I am using the following model:

```
class Friendship(models.Model):
  sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friendship_sender')
  receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friendship_receiver')
  status = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  class Meta: 
    unique_together = ["sender", "receiver"]
```

When I try to get all the pending requests with status = "0" in this way:

```
def friendship_pending(request):
  to_user = User.objects.get(fb_user_id=request.session['fb_user_id'])
  pending_requests = (Friendship.objects.filter(receiver=to_user, status='0'))
  data = serializers.serialize('xml', pending_requests, fields=('sender'))
  return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

I just get the number of the object "sender", rather than all its attributes. What I would like to get is the fields of the User (in this case sender) object, such as "name" and "fb_user_id". If I don't specify the field "sender", I still get the object number with the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user attributes, you should query for that, not for Friendships.

```
User.objects.filter(friendship_sender__receiver=to_user, friendship_sender__status='0')
```

Comment: What do you mean by friendship_sender_receiver? The class Friendship has a sender and a receiver. My aim is to get all the objects "sender", which is foreign key of User, to show name, surname and id. When I first query Friendship, I get the sender, but then I don't know how to query User to get all the data that should be in pending_request.sender.

Comment: User has an attribute `friendship_sender`, because that is the related name from Friendship.sender. Friendship has an attribute `receiver`. The double-underscore is how you query across joins.

Comment: Ok, it makes more sense, but how do I make the join too? I mean in this case I am getting an error because User doesn't have a status field, which is in friendship.

Comment: "Cannot resolve keyword 'friendship_sender_status' into field. Choices are: friendship_receiver, friendship_sender" It still doesn't resolve the "keyword into field".

Comment: You need two underscores between sender and status.